# Windows Phone application crash when double navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone Application when I press a button for navigating to Page1 and before it finishes loading it, I press button to navigate to Page2, my application crashes. Is it correct and what is the best practice to implement this behaviour?

**Update**
Generally I think, the best way for me will be to block all buttons on the screen after one of them was pressed and make them active after navigation finish, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is this case is to disable the Click event after the first click.
If your button was named b and you either assigned event handler in xaml or in codebehind 
like

```
b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonOnClick);

void ButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    b.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonOnClick);

    // Navigate away now.
}
```

Actually my sample will stop double click on current button only but you can disable other buttons as well.

in one of my apps, i maintain a List which i iterate and show / hide, enable / disable a required. all you do is iterate and set the correct property.

```
foreach(var button in myButtons)
    button.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: it ok, but how can I disable pressing Back button?

Comment: for back button you need to handle (read override) the Page's Back Key press. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.backkeypress(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call to `NavigationService.Navigate(Page2Uri)` into `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=> {...} );` as follows:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (()=> { NavigationService.Navigate(Page2Uri) });
```